# Корректная установка gcc/libc и прочих

Tags: администрирование, gcc, библиотеки, cmake, сборка

Я новичок и у меня возник следующий вопрос: 
Сижу под CentOS 7 и появилась необходимость в установке разных версий gcc, cmake, libc и прочих компонентов на одной системе. 
Начал с того, что собрал gcc 4.9.4, но когда я собираю что-то подобное, то make install, устанавливает собранное каким-то странным для меня образом. После установки я ожидаю, что cmake автоматически подтянет нужную версию компилятора(а не gcc из yum/apt) со всеми библиотеками и приходится указывать cmake пальцем, где и что искать. Подразумевается, что новая версия старше и должна быть выбрана она, но нет. И так происходит со всеми билиотеками, в то время как если ставить через checkinstall, то все подтягивается отлично.

Как правильно устанавливать подобные вещи? Как поступать, если версий библиотек должно быть несколько и не хотелось, чтобы они конфликтовали.

Comment: CMake подбирает `gcc` из `PATH`. Никакой больше специальной магии нет.

Comment: Что значит: "подтянет нужную версию"? Как cmake должен понять, какая версия вам нужна? Для этого нужно указать ему какую версию он должен взять. А для этого существует флаг CMAKE_C(XX)_COMPILER

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Речь про выбор доминирующей версии. А в случае с библиотеками вообще их нахождение. Расширил немного описание

Comment: Что значит: устанавливает собранное каким-то странным для меня образом? Что касается остального: если вы не хотите прямо указывать cmake какой компилятор юзать, но при этом чтобы он выбирал именно нужный вам, то этот компилятор должен быть дефолтным. Для этого юзайте update-alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В дистрибутивах GNU/Linux любые действия в обход пакетного менеджера будут приводить к путанице, накоплению мусора или слому системы. Пакетный менеджер yum [не поддерживает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537211/installing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-package-using-yum) установку нескольких версий одного пакета.

Для таких случаев рекомендую организовать отдельное место для установки инструментария (например /opt/toolchain1, /opt/toolchain2, ...) с правами пользователя. Во время конфигурации (вызов `./configure`) следует указывать каталог установки (например для gcc это опция `--prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>`). Тогда после запуска `make && make install` все файлы будут скопированы в нужный каталог.

Теперь как использовать установленное. В комментариях уже указывалось что cmake по умолчанию смотрит в переменную PATH. Для того чтобы поменять компилятор, в cmake есть переменная [CMAKE__COMPILER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_COMPILER) и прочие переменные для указания путей к конкретным библиотекам. Ими и нужно задавать инструментарий для конкретной сборки.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить следующее решение: сам использую несколько версий gcc:

1. gcc из набора linux x86-64
2. gcc из набора RISCV Toolchain
       newlib - riscv64-unknown-elf-
3. gcc из набора eclipse mcu
           toolchain - riscv64-none-
4. gcc из набора RISCV Toolchain linux -
               riscv64-unknown-linux-

Первый компилим в систему make install
Для остальных конфигурируем пути через configure и устанавливаем по указанным путям, переменную PATH можно указать в .profile папки /home/